# printing images in crystal reports in vb.net using typed dataset in Access

Tags: vb.net, image, ms-access, crystal-reports

i am trying to design a crystal reports in vb.net which contains a Image. I using a database as MS Access. This database is storing image in binary format. 
I am using typed dataset which  contains the image column( set its type to System.Byte())
when I drag drop the field in report while designing I can see  image border only. 
when i run the report the image is not shown. Need help

I am loading the image qith query: - 
"Select Image from Images where ImageID=1

Need your help

Comment: When you insert the picture field into the report have you right clicked on it and formatted it so that Crystal knows it's a picture?

Comment: Thanks Adrian for your comment. I had added typed dataset(Dataset1.xsd) it contains Table(Datatable1) which further contains Column(Image). I have made the datatype of the column to System.Byte(). When I drag-drop the image in crystal report I can see the Image box(only borders) appearing in the report.

Comment: Atlast I found the solution on it ,I had to link the dstasets, earlier I was trying to avoid it